# simplify relational operators with logic?

Tags: sympy

How to simplify an expression with combined relational operators?

for example: `x < 10 & x < 4` should return `x < 4`

Comment: Please add the code that you've attempted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to handle this. Here are two:

```
>>> var('x',real=True)
x
>>> solve((x<10, x<4))
x < 4
>>> And(x<10, x<4).as_set().as_relational(x)
x < 4
```